# React Native Application Error - Couldn't find a 'component', 'getComponent' or 'children' prop for the screen 'Chat'

Tags: react-native, import, export, react-props, stack-navigator

I tried to create a Chat screen but I am getting this error. I think I imported and exported everything correctly.

**Error Message**: Error: Couldn't find a 'component', 'getComponent' or 'children' prop for the screen 'Chat'. This can happen if you passed 'undefined'. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or mixed up default import and named import when importing.

This error is located at:
in StackNavigator (at App.js:60)

**Chat.js :**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native';
import { GiftedChat } from 'react-native-gifted-chat';
import {
    firebase,
    firebaseConfig,
    db,
    getUserDocument,
    realtime,
  } from "../../firebase/config";
  import "firebase/auth";
  import "firebase/firestore";
  import "firebase/database";

  const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

export default class Chat extends React.Component {

    static navigationOptions = {
        title : 'Chat',
    }
    state = {
        messages: [],
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            messages: [
            {
                _id: 1,
                text: 'Hello developer',
                createdAt: new Date(),
                user: {
                    _id: 2,
                    name: 'React Native',
                    avatar: 'https://placeimg.com/140/140/any',
                    },
                },
            ],
        })
    }

    onSend(messages = []) {
        this.setState(previousState => ({
            messages: GiftedChat.append(previousState.messages, messages),
        }))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff' }}>
                <GiftedChat
                    messages={this.state.messages}
                    onSend={messages => this.onSend(messages)}
                    user={{
                        _id: 1
                    }}
                />
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

**App.js :**

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React, { Component, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { NavigationContainer,  DefaultTheme } from '@react-navigation/native'
import {createAppContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'
import { LoginScreen, HomeScreen, RegistrationScreen, Resource4, Screen1, Screen2, Screen3, Screen4, Page1, Page2, Page3, Page4, Chat } from './src/screens'
import { firebase } from './src/firebase/config'
// import { createTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';


const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator(); 

function TabsStack() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name='HomeScreen' component={HomeScreen} />
      {/* <Tab.Screen name='Resource4' component={Resource4} /> */}
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}
const MyTheme = {
  ...DefaultTheme,
  colors: {
    ...DefaultTheme.colors,
    primary: 'rgb(255, 45, 85)',
  },
};

export default function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
  const [loggedin, setLoggedIn] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    const usersRef =  firebase.firestore().collection('users')
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        usersRef
          .doc(user.uid)
          .get()
          .then((document) => {
            const userData = document.data()
            setUser(userData)
            setLoading(false)
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            setLoading(false)
          });
      } else {
        setLoading(false)
      }
    });
    //return firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(setLoggedIn);
  }, []);

  return (
   <NavigationContainer  >
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={user ? 'Home' : 'Login'} >
        <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen"  options={{ title: '', headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#caf7e3'
           } }}>
          {props => <HomeScreen {...props} extraData={user}/>}
        </Stack.Screen>
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} options={{ title: 'Login', headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#caf7e3'
           } }}  />
       
        <Stack.Screen name="Registration" component={RegistrationScreen} />
       
        <Stack.Screen name="Resource4" component={Resource4} options={{ title: '', headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#caf7e3'
           } }} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Screen1" component={Screen1}  options={{ title: '', headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#caf7e3'
           } }}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="Screen2" component={Screen2}   options={{ title: 'COVID-19 & Pregnancy', headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#caf7e3'
           } }}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="Screen3" component={Screen3} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Screen4" component={Screen4} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Page1" component={Page1} options={{ title: '', headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#e4bad4'
           } }} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Page2" component={Page2} options={{ title: '', headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#a0829b'
           } }} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Page3" component={Page3} options={{ title: '', headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#e4bac2'
           } }} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Page4" component={Page4} options={{ title: '', headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#c197d2'
           } }} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Chat" component={Chat} options={{ title: '', headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#caf7e3'
           } }} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
//caf7e3
```

**AppNavigator.js**

```
import * as React from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'
// import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs'
import HomeScreen from '.../HomeScreen/HomeScreen.js'
import Resource4 from '.../Resources/Resource4.js'
import LoginScreen from '.../LoginScreen/LoginScreen.js'
import Chat from '...Chat/Chat.js'

const Stack = createStackNavigator()
// const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator()

function getHeaderTitle(route) {
    const routeName = route.state
      ? route.state.routes[route.state.index].name
      : route.params?.screen || 'HomeScreen'
  
    switch (routeName) {
      case 'HomeScreen':
        return 'HomesCreen'
      case 'Resource4':
        return 'Resource4'
      case 'Chat':
        return 'Chat'
    }
  }

function MainTabNavigator() {
    return (
      <Tab.Navigator
        tabBarOptions={{
          activeTintColor: '#101010',
          style: {
            backgroundColor: '#ffd700'
          }
        }}
        screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => {
            let iconName
            if (route.name == 'HomeScreen') {
              iconName = 'ios-home'
            } else if (route.name == 'Profile') {
              iconName = 'ios-person'
            }
            return <Ionicons name={iconName} color={color} size={size} />
          }
        })}>
        <Tab.Screen name='HomeScreen' component={HomeScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name='Resource4' component={Resource4} />
        <Tab.Screen name='Chat' component={Chat} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    )
  }

  function MainStackNavigator() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator  screenOptions={{
    headerShown: false
  }} initialRouteName={user ? 'Home' : 'Login'}>

        <Stack.Screen name="Home">
          {props => <HomeScreen {...props} extraData={user} component={MainScreen}/>}
        </Stack.Screen>
        {/* <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} /> */}
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen}  />
    </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

'or mixed up default import and named import when importing.' this is your problem. Your Chat class is a default export, while you have imported it in App.js as otherwise. Change its import to:

import Chat from './src/screens'

and it should work. Though I'm also skeptical that ./src/screens is the correct location because in your AppNavigator you have it listed as

import Chat from '...Chat/Chat.js'

Comment: Thanks for your response. When I do 
import Chat from './src/screens' 
I get the same error as before. And when I do
import Chat from '.src/screens/Chat'
I get "Unable to resolve module ./src/screens/Chat from C:\Users\priya\Documents\Ramitha_Projects\MTSummer2021\MTSummer2021\App.js"

My Chat.js is in a folder called 'Chat' that is in 'screens' folder in 'src' folder.

Comment: Okay yea it's definitely an incorrect path for the imports you're writing then. If you could take a screenshot of your folder structure I could answer it for you. Otherwise you'll have to read a bit more about exactly how to navigate pathing correctly for your imports. For example this line is almost certainly wrong unless you've put every single one of your screens into the same file 
import { LoginScreen, HomeScreen, RegistrationScreen, Resource4, Screen1, Screen2, Screen3, Screen4, Page1, Page2, Page3, Page4, Chat } from './src/screens'

Comment: I figured it out! Just needed to add "export { default as Chat } from './Chat/Chat'" to my index.js file and my old statement worked. Thanks for your help :)